# If a web API is given to add on a web page, how does one change the css style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using an external "API" for a web portal. All that was given was

```
<div id="cp_response_container"></div>
```

how does one change the css elements?

Comment: can you be more specific as which external api you are given .. or a more details ,,,and more code so that other fellow stackoverflow members could help you ..

Comment: as well as <script type="text/javascript" src=

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.